# MALAB Coder - Static size string in sprintf

Tags: string, matlab, char, printf, matlab-coder

How can I prevent MATLAB Coder to generate variable size code for a simple number insertion into a string?

```
for i=1:4

    name=sprintf('Data%d.bin',int8(i));
    stuff(name);
end
```

In the generated C code it uses a lot of functions like emxutil to determine the size of the generated string for sprtintf. 
I just want to say that i is only one digit. How can I do that?!
The followings also do not work

```
name=['Data',char(i),'.bin'];
```

Using the following also gives an error for generating code that LHS is fixed sized but RHS is varying:

```
coder.varsize('name',[1,14],[0,0])
```

Comment: If "i" is single digit you may want to use something simple like `char(48+i)` instead of sprintf to convert it to string. Then insert it into your string as `['Data' char(48+i) '.bin']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested the following again. It works well and also can be used for more digits, and it does not use var size stuff.

```
name=['Data',int2str(i),'.bin'];
```

Also, these can be used if we are sure that i is one digit:

```
['Data' char(48+i) '.bin']
['Data' char('0'+i) '.bin']
```